# Material UI Paper element not covering 100% of viewport height

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI `<Paper>` component that serves as a background and exists in my main React component- it's nested inside a `<ThemeProvider>`, which is nested a `<div>`, which is then nested in the `<body>`. I've applied the `viewport: 100vh` attribute to make it take the full height of the screen. It does take up the full height, but only prior to rendering another `<Paper>` component on the right hand side. Then the bottom of the paper no longer extends to the bottom of the screen:
[image: screenshot]

Beginning of App render method:

```html
return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Paper style={{ height: '100vh', boxShadow: 'none' }}>
        <Container fluid id='app'>
        .......
)
```

I tried applying the `viewport: 100vh` attribute to both the `<div>` that encloses the App component in index.js and the `<body>` element in index.html. There wasn't any difference. It may be worth mentioning that I'm using react-bootstrap Containers/Rows/Cols for my grid system at the moment (haven't switched that part to Material UI yet), but they're all nested inside the Paper, so I wouldn't expect they would be causing the problem. I also tried removing any css applied to the `<Container>` but it didn't help.

I'm also using a muiTheme for the `<ThemeProvider>` (obviously):

```html
export default function createTheme(isDarkModeEnabled) {
    return createMuiTheme({
        palette: { 
            type: isDarkModeEnabled ? 'dark' : 'light',
            primary: {
                main: '#6DD3CE',
                dark: '#639FAB'
            },
            secondary: {
                main: '#52CBC5'
            }
        },
        typography: {
            fontFamily: [ 'montserratlight', 'Times New Roman' ].join(','),
            body2: {
                fontFamily: [ 'montserratmedium', 'Times New Roman' ].join(',')
            },
            h3: {
                fontSize: '1.75rem'
            },
            button: {
                fontFamily: [ 'montserratmedium', 'Times New Roman' ].join(',')
            }
        }
    })
}
```

### Update and Solution

I did redo my layout using flexbox instead of react-bootstrap, and ultimately fixed the problem by using `min-height: 100vh` instead of `height: 100vh` for my container so it had room to expand.

Comment: I suspect that one of your containers has an attribute that is conflicting with your child's styling. Any change you can provide a MRE (perhaps via codesandbox) so we can further debug?

Comment: Sure thing, sorry for getting back to this late. If you toggle Dark Mode then click the "Enter Text" radio button, you'll see the issue at the bottom of the screen: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-night-z7e7p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `<Container>` has a bit of padding that is causing the content to go beyond its height:

[image: container too large]

This could also be due to your `<textarea />` not having an assigned height. This is a particular issue when you are in a medium-sized screen.

If you are already planning to do away with Bootstrap's layout system, consider flex box and styled containers:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <StyledHeader>Hello StackOverflow</StyledHeader>
      <StyledCol>
        <p>This is column 1.</p>
      </StyledCol>
      <StyledCol>
        <p>This is another column.</p>
      </StyledCol>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

const StyledHeader = styled.h1`
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const StyledCol = styled.div`

  height: 70%;
  width: 50%;
  & p {
    text-align: center;
  }

`;
```

CodeSandbox Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-63802170-flexbox-example-909ol

This will ultimately give you more control over the layout of the page.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, thanks! I did try adding an explicit height to the textarea, but that didn't fix it. I'm going to go learn flex box and try it out. Will confirm it as a solution after I implement it.

Comment: Two flex box references to help you on your journey! https://flexboxfroggy.com/ https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks, those were really helpful. Turns out the main problem was having an attribute of 'height: 100vh' for my container, giving it no room to expand. I changed it to 'min-height: 100vh' and it now expands to accommodate any nested elements.

Comment: @porter3 Nice! That's one great thing about using flexbox; because you are 'close to the metal' you can find those weird bugs. Glad to hear this helped!